# Añadir spinner o dialogo "Cargando.." entre 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment

Buenos días gente, tengo un problema, tengo una aplicación basada en fragments.

Un fragment Menu, con botones que según los pulses, abren otro fragment el cual reemplaza al anterior, siempre se visualiza un único fragment a la vez. El problema es, que algún fragment tarda mucho en abrirse como 2 segundos aveces, ya que hace conexiones a internet y/o accesos a bases de datos en asynctasks.

El tema es, que al pulsar el botón en el menú, se queda la pantalla parada como 2 segundos en el menú, hasta que finalmente aparece el fragment. Me gustaría que en ese tiempo que se queda pillado el menú hasta que por fin aparece el fragment, saliera un simbolo de cargando (spinner loading o algo así) o simplemente un dialogo que pusiera "cargando.."

he probado con esto

```
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();
```

El código de arriba, llega a crear el diálogo, pero nunca durante los 2 segundos que está estancado el menu fragment.
por lo que no consigo que nunca aparezca durante esos 2 segundos que se queda en pantalla el menú "lagueado" hasta que por fin aparece el nuevo fragment.

¿ Donde debería poner el códico de arriba ? en la activity que contiene a los fragments? en el propio fragment de menú, que es el que se queda pillado 2 segundos hasta que carga el nuevo fragment? o en el nuevo fragment?

No consigo que funcione de la manera que quiero, que en el menú, a la hora de ejecutar el nuevo fragment:

```
     NewAppointmentFragment fragment = new NewAppointmentFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, 
    "NewAppointmentFragment");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

En los 2 segundos que se demora, se queda visualizándose el fragment de menu "lagueado" sin un spinner ni nada!

**¿ Puede ser por que en los fragments yo haga todas las llamadas a asynctask y todas las operaciones de listview en el OnCreateView ?**

de que manera debería resolver esto?

Si alguien que entienda me puede echar una mano estaría muy agradecido!

Answer (score 0):

Yo he tenido un problema similar al tuyo y uso un asynktask con una pequeña pausa en el reloj para cuando tengo que que mostrar el spinner:

```
private class ejemploAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //region Mostrar Layaout con progressBar

        llVacio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llLleno.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        //endregion

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        SystemClock.sleep(250);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer aInteger) {
        super.onPostExecute(aInteger);


        //region Mostrar Layaout lleno

        llProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llLleno.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //endregion

    }

}
```

Espero que como idea te sirva.